# Problem with RecyclerView in Night Mode android kotlin NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-night-mode

I have a RecyclerView in my Fragment and two themes in app: Day, Night and System Default.

There is a strange problem that causes a NullPointerException. If I switch the theme to night and exit the application, and then enter it again, then a NullPointerException crashes and the application will not open again until I delete it from the phone or emulator. However, if I stay on the light theme all the time and close and open the application again, then everything will be fine.

Code for Fragment:

```
private  var _binding: FragmentListBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var rvAdapter: RvStatesAdapter
private var statesList = ArrayList<State>()
private var databaseReferenceStates: DatabaseReference? = null

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    checkTheme()
    initDatabase()
    getStates()

    binding.rvStates.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())

    binding.ibMenu.setOnClickListener {
        openMenu()
    }

    return binding.root
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

private fun getStates() {
    databaseReferenceStates?.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                for (stateSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                    val state = stateSnapshot.getValue(State::class.java)

                    statesList.add(state!!)
                }

                rvAdapter = RvStatesAdapter(statesList)
                binding.rvStates.adapter = rvAdapter
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }
    })
}

private fun initDatabase() {
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(requireContext());
    databaseReferenceStates = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("States")
}

private fun openMenu() {
    binding.drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)

    binding.navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.about_app -> Toast.makeText(context, "item clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            R.id.change_theme -> {
                chooseThemeDialog()
            }
        }

        binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        true
    }
}

private fun checkTheme() {
    when (ThemePreferences(requireContext()).darkMode) {
        0 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
        }

        1 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
        }

        2 -> {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
            (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
        }
    }
}

private fun chooseThemeDialog() {
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
    builder.setTitle("Choose Theme")

    val themes = arrayOf("Light", "Dark", "System default")

    val checkedItem = ThemePreferences(requireContext()).darkMode

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(themes, checkedItem) {dialog, which ->
        when (which) {
            0 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
                (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
                ThemePreferences(requireContext()).darkMode = 0
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            1 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
                (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
                ThemePreferences(requireContext()).darkMode = 1
                dialog.dismiss()
            }

            2 -> {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
                (activity as AppCompatActivity).delegate.applyDayNight()
                ThemePreferences(requireContext()).darkMode = 2
                dialog.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}
```

ThemePreferences class:

```
companion object {
    private const val DARK_STATUS = ""
}

private val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)

var darkMode = preferences.getInt(DARK_STATUS, 0)
    set(value) = preferences.edit().putInt(DARK_STATUS, value).apply()
```

RecyclerView in .xml code:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvStates"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@color/background"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvLabelDescription"
        tools:listitem="@layout/rv_state_list" />
```

and also code from RecyclerView Adapter:

```
inner class MyViewHolder(val binding: RvStateListBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    return MyViewHolder(RvStateListBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currentItem = stateList[position]

    with(holder) {
        with(stateList[position]) {
            binding.tvState.text = this.name

            Picasso.with(itemView.context)
                .load(this.image)
                .into(binding.ibState, object: Callback {
                    override fun onSuccess() {
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    }

                    override fun onError() {

                    }
                })

            itemView.ibState.setOnClickListener {
                val action = StatesFragmentDirections.actionListFragmentToAttractionsFragment(currentItem)
                itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return stateList.size
}
```

[image: Exception]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your crash is coming from that `onDataChange` callback - you're calling `getStates` (after `binding` has been set) but by the time the results come back and `onDataChange` tries to access `binding`, it's null again.

If I had to guess, when you call `checkTheme` and it calls `applyDayNight`, that probably does nothing if the activity is already using the theme you're applying. So if you're setting a light theme, and it's already using a light theme, no problem. (You could test this by seeing if it stops crashing if you set the system to a dark theme, assuming your app theme is a DayNight one)

But if it needs to change to a dark theme, that means recreating the `Activity` and `Fragment`. I don't know the specifics of what gets recreated now, but at the very least you're probably going to be recreating your view layout with the new theme. Which means the layout is getting destroyed, which means `onDestroyView` is getting called - and in there, you're setting `binding` to null

So I'm assuming your `onDataChange` callback is either arriving between layout (and binding) destruction and recreation, or the whole Fragment is getting destroyed and the callback is just calling a `binding` variable that's never getting restored.

---

Easiest fix is just to not set `binding` to null. Make it `lateinit` like Emmanuel says, and it'll get initialised/overwritten every time `onCreateView` is called. If the callback updates an old binding layout, it's cool, the new one will ask for an update in `onCreateView` anyway

Just make sure you're cleaning up the event listeners you're setting on `databaseReferenceStates` if you need to - if that's the reason you're clearing the binding in `onDestroyView`, the listener still has a reference to the fragment that holds that variable, and you could end up keeping dead ones in memory (otherwise you could just null-check `binding`)

Answer (score 2):

You should just use

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentListBinding

onCreateView()
    binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
```

Don't set it to null anywhere

Also move any code not responsible to create view from `onCreateView` to `onViewCreated`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is not related to the theme itself, but more to fragment/activity lifecycle. If you would turn on don't keep activities on and background then resume the app it would crash.

I think the issue is that you are leaking the fragment with the `addValueEventListener`. Since you implemented it as an anonymous class you are not able to remove it on `onStop` so your fragment leaks hence getting the null pointer exception because the view was destroyed.